# Stealing access tokens in oAuth2

Tags: javascript, security, authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0

If using the clientside flow, the callback URL contains the access token. So if the callback URL is sent over HTTP, isn't it vulnerable to being captured and misused.

If user 2 of my app, gets the access token of user 1, he can get access to user 1's account.

Also if the user copies the callback URL and sends it to someone, he is unknowingly sending the other person access to his account.

I can think of some ways of mitigating this - make callback url HTTPS, and on the client script remove the access token from the URL etc. Is that how you are expected to deal with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clientside flow sends the oauth_token in the hash part of the URL (`/path?#access_token=abcdef`), not in a query part. It is then a good idea for the receiving client to store it in a `sessionStorage` (or something else) and finally use `window.location.hash = '';` to remove it from the URL.

Comment: Thanks Tom. Yes, that was my idea as well, store the token and remove it from the url/hash. What do you think about the callback URL using HTTP. Isn't this unsafe (for e.g. I will be able to see someone's access token plain text if I can listen to the network traffic)? Should we be using HTTPS? I am just surprised this isn't enforced by Google etc. when you specify a callback URL when registering your app.

Comment: The hash isn't actually sent in a HTTP request, it's a client thing. Only the server which does the redirect gets to know the access_token, and this server is supposed to have SSL (according to the OAuth spec). A server implementation of OAuth 2 can be considered safe if the spec is fully implemented.

Comment: Ahh, I see. I was under the impression when Google redirects to the callback url, this whole url would be visible if the request/response were inspected - but that doesn't seem to be the case (checked with Fiddler). Thanks for the answer :)